# Conditionally merge two nested arrays

Tags: javascript

I have multiple nested arrays:

```
const arrayOne = [[1559692800000, 2],[1559779200000, 9], [1559865600000, 1]]

const arrayTwo = [[1559692800000, 1],[1559779200000, 1]]
```

The first number in the nested array is a unix timestamp, the second is a count. I want to merge the two arrays together and where a timestamp matches between the first and second arrays I want to add the count value together. So the above code would produce:

```
const arraysCombined = [[1559692800000, 3],[1559779200000, 10], [1559865600000, 1]]
```

I could create an empty array and loop over and push all the items in the first array in to the new array. Then loop over all the items in the second array and check if the timestamp already exists, and if it does then add the two numbers together. This seems very long-winded though.

Comment: Can you share with us how you've attempted to do this so far?  We can help you get your solution working.

Comment: What should happen when a timestamp is in array2 but not in array1

Comment: There are probably duplicates of this.  Searching Google for "site:stackoverflow.com javascript group by and count" brings up a number of relevant-looking results.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: I've added in plain text what I've tried so far. I've deleted that code since.

Comment: So can you try again and post the code, it will be beneficial for to understand where your code went wrong, else it will be just copy paste

Comment: Well it didn't go wrong. I just don't think it was a very good approach and was looking for a better solution. As I've said I've deleted that code since.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join both of the array, and use `Map and reduce`.

Use the first element of each subarray as key if it's already present then add current value with previous value else add with `0`

```js
const arrayOne = [[1559692800000, 2],[1559779200000, 9], [1559865600000, 1]]
const arrayTwo = [[1559692800000, 1],[1559779200000, 1]]

let final = [...arrayOne,...arrayTwo].reduce((op,inp)=>{
  let [key,value] = inp
  op.set(key, (op.get(key)|| 0) + value  )
  return op
},new Map())


console.log([...final])
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Haven't used Map before so learnt something here